# How to change Google Analytics API language?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I'm developing a web application that shows information from Google Analytics but i can't seem to change the language to another besides english.

I'm setting it like this:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['corechart', 'table'], 'language': 'pt'});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming you mean that you are selecting information via the API.  The API only exports data in English it wont change the values for you.

Comment: Yes, I am selecting information via the API. Well, I'll have to translate it myself then. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Psygnosis have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to log in your accounts and then Select  SETTINGS from Right Side of Screen From TOP, so you will able to see The Language Bar, so now you can choose which language you want to use.

Comment: I'm asking about the Google Analytics API, not about the Analytics itself.